# flutter fetching sub-collections

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i want to fetch sub-collections names, length and their docs.
the idea is as follow: i want to create ListViewBuilder that its itemcount is the length of sub collections (which is 2 in this case as shown in the photo) and i need each one of sub collection would be accessed in each one of the green buttons.  for example: i need the sub-collection named "day 1" would be the name of the first button, and when i click on the button... it will show me all its documents, same as the second sub-collection. how to implement that with code?

[image]
[image]

is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

First The days should be documents instead of sub-collections if there is going to be only 1 document in each of them.

With firebase there is a function called `collectionGroup("collection name")` it's job is to get all sub-collection in your firestore with a certain name, to use it in your case do like this:

`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup("week 1").get();`

this like will give you the documents of the collection week 1 in all other collections.

more on `collectionGroup` check this blog: [collectionGroup blog](https://firebase.blog/posts/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries)